# link_to using with active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, link-to

The link to the user name to its profile in a table. Using active records i am finding the name and id but not able to correctly link it.

```
<% @feedback.each do |x| %>
<td> <%= link_to "User Lab Test Results", admin_users_:x.user_id_lab_test_results %></td>
<td> <%= User.find(x.user_id).first_name %> </td>
```

Error getting: 
undefined method `user_id_lab_test_results' for #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do rake routes to see if you find a url looking like url you want

then check the named route for that

suppose the named route looks like `edit_admin_user`

your code will have

`edit_admin_user_path(x.user_id)`

i.e  `named_route_path(user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a `link_to` that will link to the user show page?

```
<td> <%= link_to "User for Lab Test Results", user_path(x.user_id) %></td>
```

(this assumes you have a route named 'user')

It might be more attractive to have the first name itself be the link...

```
<td> User for Lab Test Results </td>
<td> <%= link_to User.find(x.user_id).first_name, user_path(x.user_id) %> </td>
```